# black image when forcing download

Tags: php, html

when i click a button the browser force the image to download 
the code work it download the image with  the right size but it's all black 
im using this code :

```
    // get attachment location
    $attachment_location = "files/image.jpg";

    if (file_exists($attachment_location)) {
        // attachment exists
        // send open/save jpg dialog to user
        header('Cache-Control: public'); // needed for i.e.
        header('Content-Type: application/jpg');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image.jpg"');
        readfile($attachment_location);
        die(); // stop execution of further script because we are only outputting the jpg
        }
    else {
        die('Error: File not found.');
    }
```

Comment: I thought it was "application/jpeg"...

Comment: @Mike D I thought it was "image/jpeg" ;)

Comment: i dont know what he had before but i thought it was `image/jpeg` - also dont you have to have a `Content-length` header? not sure if thats required, i've just always done it.

Comment: can you `stat` the downloaded image and the one on the server and see if there are any size differences? Also is it possible you have other data still in the buffer? what happens if you use `echo file_get_contents()` instead of `readfile`? What happens if you call `ob_clean(); flush();` before calling `readfile`?

Comment: the right size and right name only black content

Comment: now it's say invalid image !!!!!!!!!

Comment: whats changes led to the `invalid image`?

Comment: Try to set the `content-type` to `text/plain`, just so you can see the actual output. Seeing as you are getting "invalid image" now, there might be an error message in there that could explain this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code on my test server. *(PHP5.3, Apache2.2, Win7)*
Works fine in both Firefox and IE8.

Are you sure the problem is not with your image, or with your own browser?
Which version of PHP are you using? What HTTP server? Which OS?
Which browser did you test this on?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you have other data still in the buffer? what happens if you use `echo file_get_contents()` instead of `readfile`? What happens if you call `ob_clean(); flush();` before calling `readfile`?

Also do you have `error_reporting` truned on? Try turning it off before calling `readfile` or using any of the buffer operations i mentioned above.